# How to set SelectedId of Combobox and set text of Textbox in a specific format from ViewModel in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, combobox, textbox

I am working on a textbox and combobox in my wpf app. I am sorry for weird title. Well here is the scenario:

**Xaml:**

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding PortModeList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPortModeList, Mode=OneWayToSource}" SelectedIndex="0" Name="PortModeCombo" />

<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding OversampleRateBox}" Name="HBFilterOversampleBox" />
```

**ViewModel Class:**

```
public ObservableCollection<string> PortModeList
    {
        get { return _PortModeList; }
        set
        {
            _PortModeList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PortModeList");
        }
    }

    private string _selectedPortModeList;
    public string SelectedPortModeList
    {
        get { return _selectedPortModeList; }
        set
        {
            _selectedPortModeList = value;                
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedPortModeList");
        }
    }

    private string _OversampleRateBox;
    public string OversampleRateBox
    {
        get
        {
            return _OversampleRateBox;
        }

        set
        {
            _OversampleRateBox = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("OversampleRateBox");
        }
    }
```

Here I have three requirements:

1. By using `SelectedId`in xaml I am able to select the id but I want to set the selectedid of my combobox from viewmodel class. I.e. 
   `int portorder = 2
   PortModeList->SetSelectedId(portOrder)`. How can I do something like this? or is their any other approach?
2. I need to restrict number of entries inside a textbox to 4. I.e. 1234 is entered in textbox, it should not let user exceed 4 digits.
3. I want to set the format of text in `OversampleRateBox` as: 0x__. I.e. if user wants to enter 23 present in a variable, then I shud set text as 0x23. Basically 0x should be present at the beginning.

Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the `SelectedItem` property of the `ComboBox` (as you are doing), but make the binding two-way. Then, you can set your `SelectedPortModeList` (which should be called `SelectedPortMode`) in your view model.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding PortModeList}" 
       SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPortMode}" ...
```

In the view model:

```
// Select first port mode
this.SelectedPortMode = this.PortModeList[0];
```

If you want to limit the number of characters in a `TextBox`, then use the `MaxLength` property:

```
<TextBox MaxLength="4" ... />
```

If you wish to add a prefix to the `OversampleRateBox`, one option would be to test for the presence of this in the setter for `OversampleRateBox`, and if it's not there, then add it before assigning to your private field.

**Update**

Bind your `TextBox` to a string property:

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding OversampleRateBox}" ... />
```

In the setter for your property, check that the input is valid before setting your private field:

```
public string OversampleRateBox
{
    get
    {
        return _OversampleRateBox;
    }

    set
    {
        // You could use more sophisticated validation here, for example a regular expression
        if (value.StartsWith("0x"))
        {
            _OversampleRateBox = value;
        }

        // Now if the value entered is not valid, then the text box will be refreshed with the old (valid) value
        OnPropertyChanged("OversampleRateBox");
    }
}
```

Because the binding is two-way, you can also set the value from your view model code (for example in the view model constructor):

```
this.OversampleRateBox = "0x1F";
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Requirement 1 and 2 are clear but still I am not able to figure out how to go ahead with 3rd one. Can you elaborate with a sample code pls :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean as you haven't got a 'SelectedId' defined anywhere in your view or view model. Also, you have the selected item in the SelectedPortMode property, so I would change this from a string to an actual type that represents the object. This could just be a ListItem type that has a Value and Text property for example.

Comment: Well you are right. I got it :) Now what about setting the prefix of `OverSampleRateBox` as 0x???

Comment: As I say, you could do it in the setter. However, are you intending to change the user's input on the fly as they type? It might be quite a strange experience. You could have a label before your textbox which shows '0x', and then at the point you need the value they have typed, just combine their input with a 0x prefix.

Comment: Well I had done that in my C++ app as follows: `tmp = m_filterRegs[i][4] & 0x1F;` // Lets say tmp value is 12. Then I set the string like this: `m_cicInterpolRate->setText(String(T("0x")) +String::toHexString((int)tmp));`. which basically takes `0x12`. How can this be done? :) Would appreciate if you can explain it using a code :)

Comment: Basically when user is gonna enter in textbox he can type `0x12`. I don want user to enter only 23 or such. He should enter the entire `0x23`. But my requirement is oly on startup where I want to display `0x` along with a value from `tmp` which i have shown above:) Are you able to understand what I am trying to say? :)

Comment: Bind your text box to a string property on your view model, as explained. You can set the property to the appropriate value from the view model. If you want to validate their input always starts with an 0x, then test for this in the setter of the property, and if it isn't present, then don't set the value, so when the getter is called again (from the notify of property changed), the last valid value is retrieved.

Comment: Well the requirement is just on startup. I am quiet new in WPF so I am sorry for the inconvenience. Can you elaborate it in ur answer in the form of code? :)